# Get a list of files with exceptions using pattern

Tags: r

Using only the `pattern` argument from the `list.files()` function how could I get a file list excluding some files with similar pattern?

Let's say I have this files in my working directory:

```
med_t_1_1.csv, 01_t_1_1.csv, 02_t_1_1.csv, 03_t_1_1.csv,
med_t_2_1.csv, 01_t_2_1.csv, 02_t_2_1.csv, 03_t_2_1.csv
```

I want to get the files with the pattern **t_1_1** but the one that starts with **med**:

```
01_t_1_1.csv, 02_t_1_1.csv, 03_t_1_1.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_chrs <- c("med_t_1_1.csv", "01_t_1_1.csv", "02_t_1_1.csv", "03_t_1_1.csv",
               "med_t_2_1.csv", "01_t_2_1.csv", "02_t_2_1.csv", "03_t_2_1.csv")

file_chrs[grepl("\\d_t_1_1", file_chrs)] # \\d matches and digit [0-9]

# console
[1] "01_t_1_1.csv" "02_t_1_1.csv" "03_t_1_1.csv"

# so in your working directory
list.files( pattern = "\\d_t_1_1" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression

```
S[grepl("(?<!med_)t_1_1", S, perl=TRUE)]
# "01_t_1_1.csv" "02_t_1_1.csv" "03_t_1_1.csv"
```

**Explanation of regex**

`(?<!med_)` = `(?<` looks behind, `!` does not match, `med_` is the string

> Look behind for string that does not match the string med_

`t_1_1` = `t_1_1` is string

> Look for any string that matches t_1_1

**Other example

```
S1 <- c("med_t_1_1.csv", "S_t_1_1.csv", "04_t_1_1.csv")
S1[grepl("(?<!med_)t_1_1", S1, perl=TRUE)]
# "S_t_1_1.csv"  "04_t_1_1.csv"
```